# Angular directive: get input type="number" value on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get the current value of an input field on keypress.

**My code :**

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){})
.directive('decimalPlaces', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
      ele.bind('keypress', function(e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
        var oldVal = this.value;
        console.log(key, oldVal);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SgJ/200/):

My problem is that the example works in Chrome V46.0.2490.80 but not in Firefox V41.0.2 (I'm on OS X V10.9.5).

This is what happens in Chrome:

- I press "1" -> oldVal=""
- I press "." -> oldVal="1"
- I press "2" -> oldVal="1."

This is what happens in Firefox:

- I press "1" -> oldVal=""
- I press "." -> oldVal="1"
- I press "2" -> oldVal="" <-- ???

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use `keyup` event instead? And FYI, `e.which` is normalized `var key = e.which;` (i'm not angular developper so take it with some pinch of salt).  Anyway, regarding your code, seems quite easy to debug it and check what's going wrong on FF

Comment: Using keyup only shifts the problem: in FF I get a null string on step 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

It is because type="number" is differently interpreted by browsers.

Therefore I suggest to use input type="text" and write some code to remove wrong chars.

In your situation when you type '11.' there is validation error (type="number" add number validator). And when there is validation error then model don't get that value.

To prove it I created fiddle based on your fiddle (I add form - because it can handle input errors and I print errors in form) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtr8zu3o/)

type in firefox `11.`

Some time age I create module - try demo http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number/blob/master/examples/index.html
and module link: https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number
It may not be perfect, there may be problems, but It can help a lot

Comment: I understand it's probably a validation problem: I was hoping there was some "hidden" way to get the field value in Firefox (it must be somewhere, since I see it on the page).

Comment: About the type="text", I prefer number because it allows me to enter dot or comma as decimal separator (I think it depends on browser language). Your demo would be perfect if I only could use both separators (alternatively, of course). Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: unfortunately in demo there is also thousand separator, therefore it can only be one decimal separator